# Changing the page margin in LyX

Tags: margin, lyx

does anyone knows how is it possible to the change the margines of a page in LyX?
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Document > Settings > Page Margins

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any menu's in my LyX!

Comment: Consider resetting it to the defaults then. (Perhaps take the issue to the lyx ML if it persists.)